# Use Oomph to create new workspace for existing installation

Tags: eclipse, oomph

Given an Eclipse installation and a workspace created by Oomph, is it possible to let Oomph create a second workspace with a different project setup reusing the *same* Eclipse installation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your second workspace to be automatically managed by Oomph, I think that the philosophy is to let Oomph manage your installation with your workspace.

The great thing is: the plugins (jars) are not downloaded twice. An install managed by Oomph is less than 20MB (+ the bundle pool, shared across the installations).

See my Blog Post: [Oomph changes the way you handle multiple eclipse installations](https://www.bsi-software.com/en/scout-blog/article/oomph-changes-the-way-you-handle-multiple-eclipse-installations.html).

---

That said, you can also create a second workspace with your Eclipse install (select another folder during the startup or select Menu > File > Switch Workspace). In your second workspace use File > Import… > Oomph > Projects into Workspace.

This way no installation will be created but you can import the projects you want in the second workspace.